# Automate folder creation in Azure DevOps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, automation

I'm new to Azure, and I was wondering how I could automate folder creation and file creation in Azure DevOps using Python and the Rest API? Would I have to use Azure Automation?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: automate create in where? Repository? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Create in repository, yes

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#add-a-text-file

By getting the latest commit ID on the target branch, you could use the commit ID in the above API to create a file with a new folder as its root.

Here is the sample PowerShell script:

```
$MyPat = 'PAT'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))


$URL = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepoName}/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version={BranchName}&api-version=6.0"
$header = @{
'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}


$response2=Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $URL -Headers $header


$CommitID=$response2.value[0].commitId


echo $CommitID


$URL = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepoName}/pushes?api-version=6.1-preview.2"
$header = @{


   'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}
$Body = "
{
  `"refUpdates`": [
    {
      `"name`": `"refs/heads/{BranchName}`",
      `"oldObjectId`": `"$CommitID`"
    }
  ],
  `"commits`": [
    {
     `"comment`": `"Added task markdown file.`",
      `"changes`": [
        {
          `"changeType`": `"add`",
          `"item`": {
            `"path`": `"test/tasks.md`"
          },
          `"newContent`": {
            `"content`": `"created by API`",
            `"contentType`": `"rawtext`"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $B64Pat"} -Method Post -Body $Body  -ContentType application/json
```